# How do I apply this function to a list of letters instead of only the first variable in the list?

Tags: python

The result of this output gives me "A-", however, how do i apply the function foo() to the rest of the letters in letter_grades? Language is python

```
def foo(grades):
    return next(map(lambda s: [s+"+",s,s+"-"], grades))

letter_grades = ["A","B","C","D","F"]

a_list = foo(letter_grades)
print(a_list[2])
```

Comment: What do you expect ?

Comment: Don't do this:`next(map(lambda ...))` why Are you calling `next`? You probably want `list(map(...))`

Comment: Foo adds "+", "-" or no sign in front of a str

Answer (score 2):

The `map(lambda s: [s + "+", s, s + "-"], grades)` operation builds the generator of

```
[['A+', 'A', 'A-'], ['B+', 'B', 'B-'], ['C+', 'C', 'C-'], ['D+', 'D', 'D-'], ['F+', 'F', 'F-']]
```

So as you call `next` you get only the first one, the `A` arrays, where index 2 is `A-`

---

To return the whole list of list do

```
def foo(grades):
    return list(map(lambda s: [s + "+", s, s + "-"], grades))
 # [['A+', 'A', 'A-'], ['B+', 'B', 'B-'], ['C+', 'C', 'C-'], ['D+', 'D', 'D-'], ['F+', 'F', 'F-']]
```

To flatten and get it all joined do

```
from itertools import chain
def foo(grades):
    return list(chain.from_iterable(map(lambda s: [s + "+", s, s + "-"], grades)))
# ['A+', 'A', 'A-', 'B+', 'B', 'B-', 'C+', 'C', 'C-', 'D+', 'D', 'D-', 'F+', 'F', 'F-']
```

If you want a generator and not a list, remove the `list` around

Comment: How about list comp: `[i + s for i in ["A","B","C","D","F"] for s in ["+","","-"]]`?